# QGIS Composer - Read entered textbox value in another textbox

Tags: print-composer, qgis-2, expression

I'm Limited to QGIS 2.18 composer for several reasons.

I have two textboxes.

BOX1 - User INPUT value, where user enters an integer value.
BOX2 needs to read this value to be able to calculate results.

Can I use the `item_uuid` to read value in BOX1 to calculate a result in BOX2?
If so, what expression would this be?
[image]

Comment: Can I ask, what's the end goal here? I've never seen someone using the composer like this and I'm curious what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Did you ever come up with a solution to this? I’m trying to do something similar whereby the user specifies a scheme number/name in a label off to the side of a series of semi-automated map pages, then QGIS should automatically set the scheme number/name boxes on each page to match this value. There are many pages meaning there’s a significant time saving avoiding having to manually update each page, not to mention avoiding the potential for manual error.

Comment: For version 2.18 i did not come up with a solution. Currently no longer commited to old version, so this is now up for investigation in latest version available, developing updated composers in january. I will follow up by posting my findings.

Comment: Unfortunately no solution found for this with version 3.22 either.